# A file object in Java is not able to store the character '–'.

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

A file object in Java is not able to store the character '–'. 
It changes '–' to '-'. 
Is this character ('–') not supported in Java ?

Comment: You tag this as "eclipse" and "rcp". Are you talking about `java.io.File` or something else? **That** `File` should not convert any character into any other character. Also: are you talking about the *file name* or the *content* of the file?

Comment: The question is far too vague to answer at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You have to paste your code and/or explain the context

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `byte[]` to write in the file, please use the right charset e.g. `UTF-8`

Comment: And use UTF-8 as default encoding into your text editor (Vim, Notepad++, Eclipse, Code::Blocks...)